# Compile-time check of functor

Tags: c++11, compile-time

I want to have a compile-time check in my code which ensures that a given class overloads the `()` operator, that this operator takes a `const char *` and a `size_t` as parameters and that its return type is an unsigned integer.

I have tried several code snippets taken from StackOverflow, but I am not satisfied with the solution I have written:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template<class>
struct sfinae_true : std::true_type{};

namespace detail{
  template<class T>
  static auto test(int)
    -> sfinae_true<decltype(std::declval<T>()(static_cast<const char *>(nullptr), static_cast<size_t>(0u)))>;
  template<class>
  static auto test(long) -> std::false_type;
} // detail::

template<class T>
struct is_functor : decltype(detail::test<T>(0)){ };

template <typename T, typename HashFn,
      typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
struct Calculation {
  Calculation() {
    static_assert(is_functor<HashFn>(), "BAD signature");
    typedef typename std::result_of<decltype(&HashFn::operator())(HashFn, const char *, size_t)>::type return_type;
    static_assert(std::is_unsigned<return_type>::value, "BAD return type");
  }

  T output() {
    return static_cast<T>(HashFn()(nullptr, 10));
  }
};

struct Hash {
  uint32_t operator ()(const char *buffer, size_t n) const {
    return 65;
  }
};

int main() {
  Calculation<uint64_t, Hash> c;
  c.output();
}
```

Sorry for the length of the code, I tried to keep it as small as possible.

Here is what I don't like about my code:

1. If I substitute `int` to `size_t` in the parameter list when overloading the `()` operator, there is no error at compilation, because `size_t` can be implicitly cast to `int`.
2. If the signature is incorrect (e.g. I remove the `const` when overloading the operator), the first assert fails. However, because compilation does not stop, I get three error messages, and the compiler output is somewhat cluttered

   ```
   rty.cpp: In instantiation of ‘Calculation<T, HashFn, <anonymous> >::Calculation() [with T = long unsigned int; HashFn = Hash; typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<_Tp>::value, int>::type <anonymous> = 0]’:
   rty.cpp:41:31:   required from here
   rty.cpp:24:5: error: static assertion failed: BAD signature
    static_assert(is_functor<HashFn>(), "BAD signature");
    ^
   rty.cpp:25:104: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<unsigned int (Hash::*(Hash, const char*, long unsigned int))(char*, long unsigned int) const>’
    typedef typename std::result_of<decltype(&HashFn::operator())(HashFn, const char *, size_t)>::type return_type;
                                                                                                       ^
   rty.cpp:26:75: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<unsigned int (Hash::*(Hash, const char*, long unsigned int))(char*, long unsigned int) const>’
    static_assert(std::is_unsigned<return_type>::value, "BAD return type");
   ```
3. I'd like to have a single call to static_assert, something like:

   ```
   static_assert(is_correct_functor<HashFn>(), "BAD implementation");
   ```

How can I achieve this? Thanks for your help.

I am using C++11 and compiling with g++4.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `callable_traits` to get return type and argument type of the functor, and use `std::is_same` to do assertion in `static_assert`

```
// callable_traits

namespace detail {
    template <class ReturnType, class... Args>
    struct callable_traits_base
    {
        using return_type = ReturnType;
        using argument_type = std::tuple<Args...>;

        template<std::size_t I>
        using arg = typename std::tuple_element<I, argument_type>::type;
    };
}

template <class T>
struct callable_traits : callable_traits<decltype(&T::operator())>
{};

// lambda / functor
template <class ClassType, class ReturnType, class... Args>
struct callable_traits<ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Args...) const>
: detail::callable_traits_base<ReturnType, Args...>
{};
```

---

```
struct Hash {
  uint32_t operator ()(const char *buffer, size_t n) const {
    return 65;
  }
};

static_assert(std::is_same<callable_traits<Hash>::return_type, uint32_t>::value, "");
static_assert(std::is_same<callable_traits<Hash>::argument_type, std::tuple<const char *, size_t>>::value, "");
```

[Online demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01333ff3a19b5c69)

You can check the full implementation of `callable_traits` [here](https://github.com/xlc/XLCUtils/blob/bcc0d045f05bfc2cae889d48c528bd7a3dfa5522/XLCUtils/XLCObjCppHelpers.hh#L51)

Comment: Thanks Bryan, I made a lot of progress with your `callable_traits`. I notice that when I comment out the `()` operator overload for `Hash`, I get many error messages. Is there any way to improve the compiler output in this case?

Comment: @Antonin: can you share that solution?

Comment: @Eric, I shared my final code below. I tried a few similar alternatives, but this is the one I liked best.

Answer (score 0):

I was asked to share my final code. It relies on Bryan Chen's answer, which I have already accepted. In the code below, I tried very hard to have clean error messages from the compiler (in my case g++4.8) for all "possible" error cases:

- the `HashFn` template argument is not a functor
- the return type of the overloaded `()` is not unsigned integer (in the broader sense, not just `unsigned int`)
- the parameters of the overloaded `()` are incorrect

This is because this code will go into a library and I want to make sure compile error messages are not too obscure.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
struct defines_functor_operator
{
  typedef char (& yes)[1];
  typedef char (& no)[2];

  // we need a template here to enable SFINAE
  template <typename U> 
  static yes deduce(char (*)[sizeof(&U::operator())]);
  // fallback
  template <typename> static no deduce(...);

  static bool constexpr value = sizeof(deduce<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
};

// callable_traits

namespace detail {
  template <class ReturnType, class... Args>
    struct callable_traits_base
  {
    using return_type = ReturnType;
    using argument_type = std::tuple<Args...>;

    template<std::size_t I>
    using arg = typename std::tuple_element<I, argument_type>::type;
  };
}

template <class T>
struct callable_traits : callable_traits<decltype(&T::operator())>
{};

// lambda / functor
template <class ClassType, class ReturnType, class... Args>
struct callable_traits<ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Args...) const>
  : detail::callable_traits_base<ReturnType, Args...>
{};

struct Hash {
  uint32_t operator ()(const char *buffer, size_t n) const {
    return 65;
  }
};

template <bool functor, typename H>
struct HashChecker {
  static bool constexpr valid_hash = false;
};

template <typename H>
struct HashChecker<true, H> {
private:
  typedef typename callable_traits<H>::return_type return_type;
  typedef typename callable_traits<H>::argument_type argument_type;

  static bool constexpr v1 = std::is_unsigned<return_type>::value;
  static bool constexpr v2 =
    std::is_same<argument_type, std::tuple<const char *, size_t>>::value;

  static_assert(v1, "Invalid return type for HashFn");
  static_assert(v2, "Invalid parameters for HashFn");

protected:
  static bool constexpr valid_hash = v1 && v2;

};

template <typename T, typename HashFn,
      typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
struct Calculation
  : HashChecker<defines_functor_operator<HashFn>::value, HashFn> {

  typedef HashChecker<defines_functor_operator<HashFn>::value, HashFn> HC;

  static_assert(defines_functor_operator<HashFn>::value,
        "HashFn needs to overload '()' operator");

  Calculation() {
  }

  template <typename U = T>
  typename std::enable_if<HC::valid_hash, U>::type output() {
    return static_cast<U>(HashFn()(nullptr, 10));
  }

  template <typename U = T>
  typename std::enable_if<!HC::valid_hash, U>::type output() {
    return static_cast<U>(0u);
  }

};

int main()
{
  Calculation<uint64_t, Hash> c;
  c.output();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another very short solution:

```
template <typename T, typename Signature>
struct is_callable: std::is_convertible<T,std::function<Signature>> { };
```

You could then use if for your specific signature like this:

```
struct Hash {
  uint32_t operator ()(const char *buffer, size_t n) const {
    return 65;
  }
};

bool is_valid_fcn = is_callable<Hash,uint32_t(const char*, size_t)>::value;
```